# HTMLUnit collecting all links by class name

Tags: hyperlink, htmlunit, scrape

I would like to scrape / collect all the links on a page under a specific class name

e.g. HTML
Agriculture (92)

```
<a href="http://www.specificurl/page.html" class="generate">Agriculture</a>
```

I have been toying with the following pieces of code:

```
   List<?> links = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='generate']/@href");

   OR
 List<?> links = page.getAnchors();
    System.out.println(links);
```

The getByXPath option returns null and the other option grabs all anchors.  Is there a way to grab the links into a list?

Comment: Is there anyway to scrape all the links from a page? I need to scrape products and believe that grabbing all the product url's first then clicking through each one is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible XPath but I was having issues narrowing it down. (I can look into a better XPath if necessary, but for now this one worked:

```
List<?> links = page.getByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/@href").asList()
```

I'm not quite sure why it wasn't allow us to grab it by that class name.

Let me know how it works for you when you get the chance

Comment: The URL is http://www.wholesalepages.co.uk/ukwholesalers/ want all category links.

I could use a AnchorByText and enter all the link text's but that wouldn't be very clean.  I have tried the above getByXPath and its returning null, which I think means I have the path wrong??

What I tested:
List<?> links = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='generate']/href");
     
    List<?> links = page.getByXPath("//html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a[@class='generate']/href");

Comment: @Doug Stewart I have updated my answer with a working XPath. (I feel that the XPath could be better as it should be able to be grabbed by the class though)

Comment: Sorry for the delay I had been away.  Yeah this has worked, awesome thanks.  I had the remove the .asList() at the end as I didn't have it declared.  Usually would this place the result into a list?  At the moment the results I get look like: [DomAttr[name=href value=http://www.wholesalepages.co.uk/ukwholesalers/agriculture-suppliers-3000_1.html], I'm just wanting the links as the next step is to scroll through clicking each link.

Comment: @Doug Stewart Try using `.asText()` or `links.textContent`. One of those should definitely work, let me know how that goes. I prefer using Groovy for doing small task like this. In groovy the next step would be simple: `links.each { //do task here }`

Comment: Sorry I haven't used Groovy and quite new to Java to be honest.  I have tried .asText and textcontent but as its a List<?> it wont do it, bugger :(

Comment: @Doug Stewart at the moment the only alternatives I can think of would then be `.getValue()` or perhaps saving it to a string, using `.asText()` or `.textContent` on the string, and then pushing the string into the list. (all of that done in a loop of course).